# Appcelerator scope issue when clicking a view

Tags: javascript, scope, appcelerator

I'm going crazy here trying o work out why the scoping of my variable won't pick up the right value from a loop of 60 items from a DB in my Appcelerator project.

My map marker displays the correct label, but when I click it, no matter what combo of scoping I try, I cannot get the correct value in the alert. It just returns the 60th entry every time.

Likely a schoolboy error, but this is driving me nuts.

This is my function

```
function loadAnimals() {

var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB');

var getSpecies = db.execute('select * from species');
while (getSpecies.isValidRow()) {
    var speciesID = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesnid');
    var speciesName = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesname');
    var speciesDesc = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesdescription');
    var speciesLatitude = getSpecies.fieldByName('specieslatitude');
    var speciesLongitude = getSpecies.fieldByName('specieslongitude');
    var speciesConStatus = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesconservationstatus');
    var speciesMarkerFilename = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesiconfilename'); 
    var speciesMarkerIcon = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesmapicon');
    var speciesMarkerURI = getSpecies.fieldByName('speciesmapiconurl');
    var speciesImageFullPath = speciesMarkerURI.replace("public://", "http://myurl.com/");
    var speciesImageFullPath = speciesImageFullPath.replace(" ", "%20");
    var imageFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, speciesMarkerIcon);
    var iconFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, speciesMarkerFilename);


        var annotationView = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor: '#222222',
            width: 150,
            height: 75,
            layout:'vertical'
        });

        var addtoTourView = Ti.UI.createView({
            height:20,
            backgroundColor:'#6ea108'
        });


        var addtoTourTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color: '#FFF',
            text: 'ADD TO TOUR',
            width: 150,
            height: 15,
            top:3,
            textAlign: 'center',
            font: {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        });

        var annotationTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color: '#FFF',
            text: 'test',
            width: 150,
            height:15,
            top:0,
            textAlign: 'center',
            font: {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            }
        });

        var blankView = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor: '#222222',
            width: 1,
            height: 73,
            borderRadius: 0
        });

        annotationView.add(addtoTourView);

        addtoTourView.add(addtoTourTitle);
        annotationView.add(annotationTitle);

        annotations.push(Map.createAnnotation({
            latitude: speciesLatitude,
            longitude: speciesLongitude,
            title: ' ',
            //pincolor: Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
            image: iconFile,
            animate: true,
            myid: speciesID,
            rightView: annotationView,
            leftView: blankView
        }));

        addtoTourView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            //alert(speciesName + ' has dded to Tour');

            var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                message: 'Added to your Tour',
                ok: 'Continue',
                title: speciesName //this is the 60th entry, not the correct one
              });
              dialog.show();

            // do the insert into the DB
            var db = Ti.Database.open('myDB');
            db.execute('INSERT INTO tour (speciesnid) VALUES (?)', speciesID); // same with this ID, needs to the correct ID
            db.close();

        });

        annotationTitle.text = speciesName;


    //load up the next record
    getSpecies.next();

}; 
// close the database
getSpecies.close();

// add markers to map
mapview.annotations = annotations;
```

};// end of loadAnimals fucntion

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can explain the problem of the scope.  But can you tell me what map service this is (it's not Google Maps, but what is it)?  Then maybe I can help you better with the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your annotations array to add to to the map add your title to the annotation paramters as well as the speciesID which you are setting with the key - myid.

```
annotations.push(Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude: speciesLatitude,
    longitude: speciesLongitude,
    title: ' ',
    //pincolor: Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    image: iconFile,
    animate: true,  
    myid: speciesID,           // We'll be querying this
    myname: speciesName,       // and also this
    rightView: annotationView,
    leftView: blankView
}));
```

Then add your event listener once onto the map object instead of each individual annotation object. This manages memory more efficiently and is the correct way to add it. Don't add the event listener on for every annotation, this is bad practise.

```
// Handle click events on any annotations on this map.
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.info("speciesID " + evt.annotation.myid + " clicked, speciesName: " + evt.annotation.myname);
});
```

On this single event listener you can now create your alert dialog and DB insert by accessing each annotations individual properties by inspecting

```
evt.annotation
```

On the Map object you can do the following as well:

The `click` event includes a value which you can interrogate `clicksource`

This clicksource will let you know the source - `pin, annotation, leftButton, rightButton, leftView, rightView, title, or subtitle` which you can use in the event listener.

Also available is the source object that fired the event - `source`. You can then test if the clicksource is not null and the source is coming from the "ADD TO TOUR" element that you want to place the trigger on. still getting all your annotation properties from `evt.annotation`

Comment: Hi Michael, that snippet works fine, however it is the actual annotation itself I need feedback from. I need to click the annotation first, which brings me up my custom view (annotationView) with the speciesName inside and the ADD TO TOUR label before returning anything. It is the annotationView click I need to listen for, and this is where it is returning the last entry rather than the correct annotation mid or myname. Make sense?

Comment: Hi Simon, that makes sense, I've edited the post to cover two of the click event's Properties that you can use to solve that issue, so you can base your click event on the customView and still access the correct annotation values from evt.annotation.

Emmanuel's explanation covers the reason why your label is returning the last entry.

Comment: @SimonHume Did that extra information solve your issue? I've just done this on an application I'm currently developing so I can go into more detail if needed.

Comment: The client wanted a custom annotation view, and it would seem that it is actually impossible for that to respond to the click event. So I'm going to have to slightly refactor it to use the rightImage instead and hope that that can solve the issue. Will be doing that this afternoon, so hopefully your code should fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Michaels solution sounds right.

Let me post what I was gonna say anyway. I focus on explaining the scope problem, on why your code doesn't do what you expected.

---

In javascript the scope is bound to the function.  When you declare a variable within a loop (for/while/do...) things can get a little confusing.  You are not creating new variables, you are just overriding the value of the first (and only) variable with that name.

So, you have 1 variable in function loadAnimals, called speciesName.  In the while-loop you just override the value of that variable.  After the 60'th iteration, the variable just remembers the last thing you set it to.

When the client clicks on the marker, the loop is finished, the value has been set a long time ago.

---

Notice: there are probably solutions provided by your map service, but I don't know about that.

- 1 solution: 'this'.

The 'this' variable tells you what has been affected.  Inside a onClick callback, this is the element that was clicked on.

The solution to your problem will probably involve 'this'.  But I'm not sure exactly how.

Here an example of what I mean.

```
<h2>Click on the animal</h2>
<p>dog</p>
<p>cat</p>
<p>hamster</p>
<script>
function loadAnimals() {
  var speciesName = '';
  var animalElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (var i=0; i<animalElements.length; i++) {
    speciesName = animalElements[i].innerHTML ; // notice, this variable will be overridden, so this variable is useless within the onClick callback.
    animalElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // variable 'this' is the <p> that was clicked on.  
      var value_clicked_on = this.innerHTML;
      alert(value_clicked_on);
    });
  }
}
window.onload = loadAnimals;
</script>
```